# Selecting ID in a certain order specified within IN operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to try to select a certain set of numbers in a particular order, for use with loops.

```
SELECT ID 
FROM filter 
WHERE id in (87, 97, 117, 52, 240, 76, 141, 137, 157, 255, 186, 196, 133,
             175, 153, 224, 59, 205, 65, 47, 105, 80, 113, 293, 161, 145,
             192, 149, 231, 91, 101, 109, 215, 121, 125, 64, 41, 291, 367,
             388, 391, 462, 467)
```

Doing this returns results sorted by ID, rather than in the order I specified. In most other similar questions a preferred answer was using CASE for particular  entries, but what about selecting hundreds of records in a predetermined order?

Comment: y u need to order in such a strange manner? Is there any logic behind this??

Comment: There is a similar issue solved here for MySQL. Take a look, it might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134379/returning-query-results-in-predefined-order

Comment: @Raj this is actually a pretty common requirement - the UI should display things in the same order they were listed in a combo box or text box by the user, for example.

Answer (score 5):

If you have hundreds of items, then use a derived table, such as:

```
select f.id
from filter f join
     (values(1, 87), (2, 97), (3, 117), . . .) as v(ord, id)
     on f.id = v.id
order by ord;
```

Comment: (This is a good way to do it, but I couldn't let you call that a temporary table, sorry. :-))

Comment: This is a clever solution. I'd looked around to do inline derived tables like that in the past and hadn't seen this syntax before. It works in postgres. Kudos.

Comment: Thanks, this is a creative solution! Is there any way to use an incremental function in ord for (ord, id)?

Comment: @Orin . . . Not really.  I mean, you could define a temporary table with an `identity` column, but that seems like overkill.